# executing Runtime.getRuntime.exec(String cmd)

Tags: java, video

Hi
I am trying to execute the command string with Runtime.getRuntime.exec(String cmd).What

i'm actually trying to extract the I frames from video using the MPlayer and it is

installed in the different directory than that of my eclipse workspace.

I'm using the java code like the below

```
C:\\\Program Files\\\MPlayer for Windows mplayer file.mp4 -benchmark   -noframedrop -ao null -vo jpeg:outdir=iframes  -vf  framestep=I
```

the actual command to extract using DOS is

```
"mplayer file.mp4 -benchmark   -noframedrop -ao null -vo jpeg:outdir=iframes  -vf  framestep=I".
```

The ECLIPSE WORKSPACE is in my d: drive.And the Mplayer is in c:\program files\Mplayer for windows.

Eclipse IDE shows the exception as:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\MPlayer for Windows": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at myvideo1.main(myvideo1.java:39)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: just add `mplayer` in your PATH

Comment: Post your code, right now it seems that you're executing a folder

Comment: i think that might be the problem as well -- have you missed a set of forward slashes?

Comment: hey i was a typing mistake i used only \\ not \\\ Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\MPlayer for Windows mplayer file.mp4 -benchmark   -noframedrop -ao null -vo jpeg:outdir=iframes  -vf  framestep=I "); This is the only line which i use to extract i frames.

Comment: Which PATH?,Where should i give the path of MPlayer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
exec("\"C:\\Program Files\\MPlayer for Windows\\mplayer\" file.mp4 -benchmark   -noframedrop -ao null -vo jpeg:outdir=iframes  -vf  framestep=I");
```

I surrounded the command in \" since the path contains spaces and added a missing \ in front of mplayer.

Comment: Hi laz i tried what you have given above but it shows same error and that 'mplayer' is not a folder it is the part of command:- mplayer file.mp4 -benchmark   -noframedrop -ao null -vo jpeg:outdir=iframes  -vf  framestep=I

Comment: Sure, I recognize that mplayer is the executable, not a directory. The string I provided doesn't treat it as a directory though. The '\' after mplayer is to escape the '"' character within the string. You need the '"' since the directory path contains spaces.